# Conditional doesn't make sense

Tags: python

I have a error handle module, here is one that error handle a license plate:

```
def is_plate(prompt=""):
    format_plate = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]{3}\d{3}$')
    while True:
        p = input(prompt).upper()
        if format_plate.match(p):
            return p
        else:
            print("Invalid license plate, try again. Your license plate needs to be in this format:(abc123)")
```

I imported that module to implement it in one of my method in my program, Here is a snippet of my program:

```
import error_handle as eh
class Car:
    def __init__(self,name,car_type,reg_nr):
        self.owner = name
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.reg_nr = reg_nr

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner},{self.car_type},{self.reg_nr}'
class Garage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parking_log_list = []
        self.account_list = []

def changing_info(self,license_plate):
    for car in self.account_list:
        if license_plate == car.reg_nr:
            edit_choice = int(input("Choose what you like to change:\n1.License Plate\n2.Name\n3.Car Type\n"))
            if edit_choice == "1":
                car.reg_nr = eh.is_plate("State your new license plate: ")
            if edit_choice == "2":
                car.owner = input("State your Full name: ")
            if edit_choice == "3":
                car.type = eh.is_alpha("State your new car type: ")
garage = Garage()
license_plate = eh.is_plate("State your license plate: ")
garage.changing_info(license_plate)
```

When I run the program this is the following output:

```
State your license plate: abc456
```

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It doesn't execute the next line of code

When I change the conditional statement to this:

```
if license_plate != car.reg_nr:
```

It continues to execute the next line

I don't understand why it works with != operator, shouldn't it be the == operator instead?, or is it something wrong with my function on my error handle module?

Comment: Please fix the indentation first.

Comment: `for car in self.account_list:` What are you expecting this loop to do?  That list is always empty.  There is no code that would add anything to that list.  This loop stops immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It's running when you have the `!=` operator because at your `for` loop you are looping through `self.account_list` although when it is looping, this list is empty. So it is setting `car` to `None`. Because of this it isn't executing that code with the `==` operator because the license plate isn't equal to `None`.